# How to save the "id" of intersection in "rgeos::gIntersection" function in R

Tags: r

How to save the `id` in

```
f1= rgeos::gIntersection(straightline, as(polygon,"SpatialLines"),byid=TRUE)
```

function? I want to save the `id` used in the above function as a seperate vector.

Sample output of the above function is:

> ```
>       x        y
> 1 1  9.846526 5.492031
> 2 1  9.790061 6.829593
> 2 1  7.930192 7.131635
> 3 1  7.948721 8.623646
> 5 1  6.929719 9.358367
> 5 1  5.673470 9.390850
> 6 1  4.674609 8.566208
> 7 1  3.842553 8.012072
> 8 1  2.094192 8.092529
> 8 1  1.615038 6.810696
> ```

I want to have the first (`id`) column, that is,

```
col_1= 1 2 2 3 5 5 6 7 8 8.
```

Comment: `sapply(res@polygons, function(x) x@ID)`

Comment: @shadow. Thanks for your attention. Could you please explain what are 'res'  and ' polygons' ?

Comment: The `res` was what you call`f1`. The `polygons` is one of the slots of the `SpatialPolygons` class.

Comment: @shadow Still it is showing a error: Error in f1$polygons : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. Though I got the answer from another question (thanks to Spacedman).  Answer is first get "rownames(coordinates(f1))" and then "as.numeric(do.call(rbind,strsplit(rownames(coordinates(f1))," "))[,1])"